# How can you pack an array of 2 chars + 2 null characters with python's struct?

Tags: python, struct, binary

Would something like this work?

```
var = struct.pack('2sb', code, 0)
```

where code is a 2 char string.

I want to pack 2 chars + 2 null characters

I.e letters "ME" followed by 2 null characters

Comment: What do you mean by array? What exactly is the object you want to pack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code produces «*"ME" followed by two null characters*»:

```
var = struct.pack('2s2b', 'ME', 0, 0)
print repr(var)
```

Result:

```
'ME\x00\x00'
```

more simply, so does this:

```
var = 'ME\x00\x00'
print repr(var)
```